# Mac host, virtualbox does not allow Ctrl-Alt

Tags: virtualbox

Installed lubuntu in virtualbox.

Inside lubuntu, I launched application lxhotkey.

Tried to create a new hotkey with Ctrl-Alt-S.

Ctrl-Alt, when pressed, shows that lubuntu is registering **no key**. Ctrl on its own is fine, Alt on its own is fine. But the moment both are pressed together, it seems **no key press** is registered at all. It's like those 2 keys in effect **cancel each other**.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt is reserved by the virtualbox to release the pointer. Whenever you press those keys mouse interaction is transferred from vm to host

Comment: Is there any way to disable that Ctrl-Alt hotkey?

Comment: There is a host key feature that allows the vm to capture keyboard interaction. It usually is right Ctrl. It switches between the host and the VM and lets keyboard capture. Go to preferences -> input and check the keyboard shortcuts there. Play with the settings a bit and you will find what suits you

Comment: I have that "*host key*". It's my Mac's command key (left). I use it to release mouse and keyboard from the VM, yes. Problem is, virtualbox now captures both *host key* and Ctrl-Alt. I need virtualbox to ignore Ctrl-Alt. Possible?

Comment: Go to Preferences -> input and take a screenshot of the shortcuts on Virtual Machine tab. Update your question with the screenshot. Or try changing the combination of your hotkey to right Control + Alt. PS. Does any other combination work? Is there a possibility that the VM does not capture either Ctrl or Alt?